# Share a Folder with Files from Windows to Linux Guest System in VMWare

Tags: centos, mount, vmware

can someone help me how to share a folder from windows host system to linux guest system? My Linux distro is centos and linux is my guest system. I am a beginner in linux preparing for LPIC 1. Any learning resources for LPIC1 is also appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use a USB thumb drive and mount it in your guest OS.

Comment: You could also create a shared folder on Windows and then mount it as a network mount on the linux system.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard:

In VMWare you can simply (drag and drop) a file into your subsystem or even (copy and paste) it.

Also it has a feature called *shared files*.

[Take a look here](https://geek-university.com/vmware-player/enable-a-shared-folder-for-a-virtual-machine/).

Answer (score 0):

And about learning linux

Linux is more grafical than even mac and Windows and every thing is change able in linux

I suggest you use something like dual boot instead and make it your main operation system

And red hat has ended support and updates of centos so I suggest you using something else

If you wanna debian based ubuntu and mint are very grafical and popular

And if you wanna something from red hat like centos ,fedora is fairly good